# How to open a file in iOS using C?

Tags: ios, c, swift, posix

**Solution**

There was no error, I didn't pay attention. Thanks to Rob for pointing this out

---

I have an iOS app that need to read files using a C library.

I only get <strike>permission denied error (13)</strike> no such file or directory when I try to access the file from the C function, and I can't find the cause. It doesn't happen when I create, read or write using Swift.

I tried several methods to create file URL inside the user data container, nothing works with C, it only works with Swift.

Even when the file is being created with Swift, being opened, read and verified before and after the C call, it only have errors in C.

### Things I tried

```
// I tried different paths before and added the filename to these directories
// FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
// FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

let path: String = NSTemporaryDirectory().appending("test_file.txt")
FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path.path)
// true

XCTAssertNoThrow(try "test".write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), atomically: true, encoding: .utf8))
        XCTAssertNoThrow(try FileManager.default.setAttributes([FileAttributeKey.posixPermissions: 0o777], ofItemAtPath: path))

// call C
test_read_file(path)

FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path.path)
// true
```

```
// test_read_file.c
int test_read_file(const char* path) {
  access(file_path, W_OK);
  // returns 0
  
  open(path, O_RDONLY);
  // returns 13

  // errno is 2 (ENOENT: No such file or directory)

  return 0;
}
```

<strike>Correction</strike>
The `errno` value is 2

```
ENOENT 2 No such file or directory
```

Comment: Thanks, I followed the docs and from what I understand, these URLs are sandboxed, all in the user data container. I can read and write files in Swift, but nothing works with C, even when I create a file and read it in Swift before and after a C call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 13 return value is a file handle, not an error code, and suggests your code is working exactly as you expect.

[`open`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/open.2.html) returns a non-negative value for success, and -1 for failure. To check the specific error, you check `errno`.

Comment: Yes thanks, I think I tried too many things and confused it )  errno has the value `ENOENT`

Comment: `errno` indicates the value for the last thing that returned an error anywhere in the system. Very likely something inside of one of the methods you ran (possibly `write`) checked for some file existing (likely as part of the "atomic" write/delete/move step), and so `errno` would be left as "file not found" or `ENOENT` until some other operation returned an error.